# Wrap JSON with square brackets using JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have this JSON

```
{
  "ID" : "fadfds2sdfs23",
  "JSON_TEXT" : {
    "ID" : "20220506000006073",
    "name" : "firstName lastName"
  },
  "STATUS" : "ACTIVE"
}
```

This is the output that I would like to have

```json
[
  {
    "ID": "fadfds2sdfs23",
    "JSON_TEXT": {
      "ID": "20220506000006073",
      "name": "firstName lastName"
    },
    "STATUS": "ACTIVE"
  }
]
```

I'm trying to find resources about JOLT but rarely find the easy to grasp one. For removing the brackets is easier than this.

Please kindly help me (if possible please guide me to the spec too)
Thank you very much.

Comment: sorry, I've edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use just a single **shift** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "[]"
    }
  }
]
```

where whole value represented by **`@`** is wrapped up by square brackets **`[]`**

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use two operation cardinality and shift for this

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "objeto.&"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "objeto": "MANY"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "objeto": ""
    }
  }
]
```